# Merge C# and C++ code into single EXE

Tags: c#, .net, dll, linker, c++-cli

I have a small WPF application written in C# using VS2008.  For one particular task I would like to use some C++/CLI code (since it requires heavy native interop).

I know I can compile the C++/CLI code as a DLL and then reference this from the C# app, but that seems silly when the code in question is going to be fairly small.  I want to build them into the same file.  (And without extracting a DLL at runtime.)

Via some command-line-compiler magic (similar to that shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/texblog/archive/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications.aspx)) I have managed to successfully get this to compile and work when compiling C++ code into a C# DLL, for a different application.

When trying the same thing to compile C++ code into a C# EXE, however, while the compile and link works fine, trying to run the resulting executable results in the following error:

> Error while trying to run project: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019)

The command lines are basically:

```
cl /nologo /clr /Zi /MDd /DWIN32 /D_LIB /FUmanaged.dll /c interface.cpp /FoDebug\interface.obj
csc /target:module /addmodule:Debug\interface.obj /r:managed.dll App.cs MainWindow.xaml.cs Debug\MainWindow.xaml.g.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs /out:Debug\Program.netmodule
link /entry:TestApp.App.Main /subsystem:Windows /clrimagetype:ijw /debug /ltcg /manifest /out:Debug\TestApp.exe Debug\App.netmodule Debug\interface.obj
```

Any ideas where it's going wrong?  (managed.dll is a separate C# DLL containing common definitions required by both parts of the code.  I'm ok with keeping this separate and it's not really related to the problem at hand, but I've included it for completeness.)

The link command line for the working DLL version is basically the same except that it uses `/dll` instead of `/entry: /subsystem: /clrimagetype:`.  I've tried removing each of those and only the last seems optional and removing it did not help.

Comment: Don't you need the /unsafe option on csc ?

Comment: *that seems silly when the code in question is going to be fairly small* Why? Afaiac the only real disadvantage (if it really is) is that you have to ship an extra file. For the rest you get advantages (like you can replaye dll without main exe), and you wouldn't even have to fix the problem in your question :P

Comment: Programmers go through extremes to avoid a setup.exe, making their lives pretty miserable in the process.  I suspect only success when you use csc.exe to create *only* the module for the C# code and let the linker merge it with the cl.exe output.

Comment: @HansPassant: but that's what I'm doing.  Only link.exe is capable of generating a single-executable file from multiple modules like this.

Comment: @stijn: As for why, it's mostly just "because I want to" in this case.  In the other case where I (successfully) did it with a DLL, it was for obfuscation reasons -- there was some data that I wanted to hide within a larger DLL and make it harder for an outside party to locate or alter.  (Not impossible, of course -- but I didn't want "blindingly obvious" which is what it would have been if it were in a third separate DLL.)

Comment: That's not what you are doing, you are passing interface.obj to csc.exe

Comment: Via addmodule.  This (unlike what link does) merely makes csc aware of the code in that module and allows C# code that calls into the module to actually compile.  Without this it would be impossible to actually use the C++ code.  The actual contents of the obj do not end up in the netmodule produced by csc.  (It's basically just like referencing an external assembly, except that it's referencing a different internal module.)